# How to interact with a button using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some information from this [page (Binance announcements)](https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/new-cryptocurrency-listing?c=48&navId=48)
I am trying to go through all the announcements and scrape the data from the announcements. however, I am having trouble with getting my script to navigate to the next announcements page in order to get all the New Cryptocurrency Listing announcements.

could any please advise on how i could overcome this issue

here is my current code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
import time
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)  # Adjust the timeout as needed

driver.get("https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/new-cryptocurrency-listing?c=48&navId=48")

with open('announcements.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Title', 'Released On', 'Content', 'Links'])  # Write the header row

    announcement_count = 0  # Initialize the counter

    while True:
        try:
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "a")))  # Wait for at least one <a> tag to be visible
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Timed out waiting for page to load.")
            break

        links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a") if "https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/" in link.get_attribute("href")]

        if not links:
            print("No more announcements found.")
            break  # Exit the loop if no announcement links are found

        for link in links:
            driver.get(link)
            time.sleep(5)  # Static wait for content to load

            title = "Title not found"
            release_time_date = "Release time and date not found"
            content = "Content not found"
            links_str = ""

            try:
                title = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h1').text
                release_time_date = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.css-1563tgu').text
                content_area = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'css-1muhu5j')
                content = content_area.text
                links_in_content = " | ".join([a.get_attribute('href') for a in content_area.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')])
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass  # Continue even if some elements are not found

            writer.writerow([title, release_time_date, content, links_str])
            announcement_count += 1  # Increment the counter for each announcement processed

        try:
            next_page_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "next-page")))
            next_page_button.click()
        except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException):
            print("No next page button found.")
            break  # Exit the loop if no "Next page" button is found or clickable

driver.quit()
print(f"The announcements have been saved to 'announcements.csv'. Total announcements found: {announcement_count}")
```

thanks

Comment: can you try with `next_page_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Next Page"]"]')))`
instead ?

Comment: i still do not find the button

Comment: you could use ".execute_script()" selenium method and run a JS script like "if(document.querySelector(selector)) { document.querySelector(selector).click() }"

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the page you will find two elements with the same ID **next-page** also before that you need to handle the cookies pop-up which is displayed when we visit the page. So you can do it as below.

```
accpt_cookies_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Accept Cookies & Continue')]")))
accpt_cookies_button.click()

next_page_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"((//button[@id='next-page'])[2])")))
next_page_button.click()
```

Comment: I tried this and it did accept the cookies but i was still unable to get the button to be clicked/ found

Comment: @LewisRevel does it throw any exception could you provide the details on this